# combining live recording audio in another audio file iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

Does someone knows how we can combine our current recording into another background playing music? I need some sample code for this. I want to create something like karaoke application in which we can record our voice over an instrumental music.

Comment: would hoped to see some answer on this...